How to add back order class in size option label if variation availability 0?
{%- unless product.has_only_default_variant -%}
<variant-radios id="variant-radios-{{ section.id }}" class="no-js-hidden" data-section="{{ section.id }}" data-url="{{ product.url }}" {% if update_url == false %} data-update-url="false" {% endif %}  {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
{%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
<fieldset class="js product-form__input {{ option.name }}">
<legend class="form__label">{{ option.name }}</legend>
{% if option.name == 'Color' %}
{% for value in option.values %}
<input id="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}" type="radio" name="color" value="{{ value | escape }}" {% if option.selected_value == value %}checked{% endif %}>
<label class="color-swatch {% if product.variants[0].option1 == value and product.variants[0].inventory_quantity == 0 %}preorder{% endif %}" 
style="background-image:url({{ value | append: '.jpg' | file_url }})" 
for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}" data-count="{{ forloop.index0 }}"></label>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% if option.name == 'Size' %}
{% for value in option.values %}
<input id="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}" type="radio" name="size" value="{{ value | escape }}" {% if option.selected_value == value %}checked{% endif %}>
<label for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}" class="preorder-corner {% if product.variants[0].option2 == value and product.variants[0].inventory_quantity == 0 %}back-order{% endif %}">{{ value -}}</label>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</fieldset>
{%- endfor -%}
</variant-radios>
{%- endunless -%}

I have tried to add the "back-order" class if the inventory is 0, but the class is only visible on the first option. I want to add a feature where the size options reload based on the color selection, similar to how it functions on the web site you can check here.
